# Why do I get an output of '0' with this function?

Tags: php

Can someone explain why the below function only echos '0'?

```
$year   = date('Y');


    function LastElements_shortcode() {
        global  $year;
        return "Published July 1, " . $year . " The three elements for our summer issue were:<span style='color:#ffd997;'> Miasma, Simmer, and Whimsy</span>.";
    }
```

The below code within an 'if' statement outputs a variable just fine.

```
function elements_shortcode() {
    global  $elements;
    return  "<span style='color:#ffd997; font-weight:bold;'>" . $elements . "</span>";
}
```

Comment: Inside your elements_shortcode functions change the return to echo

Comment: The code at the top does not work. The code at the bottom with the elements_shortcode() works as it should.

Comment: Yes, and that didn't work.

Comment: no idea, use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: works fine for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZChsoG

Comment: it always works for you @Dagon

Comment: Are you saying it only returns `0`, nothing else? Or does it return `"Published July 1, 0 The...etc.`?

Comment: What you did would work on a normal page, but then somehow it stops several javascript functions that I have.

Comment: Yes, it returns 'Published July 1, 0 The'...etc.

Comment: No. As globabl $3elements is not outside of its function but still echos like it should.

Comment: probably scope issue, to much missing information, back to work

Comment: @Dagon your life is now complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just replaced `global $year` with `$year = date('Y');` within my function.

Works like a charm!

Comment: praise Buddha. global is universally frowned upon, so try not to use it anyway.